# C# DateTime ToString with custom format independent of culture

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a C# application that receives a `DateTime` instance and uses its string representation utilizing `DateTime.ToString()`. I want to format the string using in the following way:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff
```

What I can't seem to understand from documentation of `DateTime.ToString()` is how (if at all) I should deal with Culture info in order to ensure that the string representation is consistent across machines and regions. Is this sufficient:

```
var DateTime = DateTime.Now;
var datetimeString = dateTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff");
```

Or do I need to use the overloaded method with some `Culture` value (Maybe `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`). Any help on understanding this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Culture is only useful when you _don't_ explicitly define the format. You're explicitly defining the format, so I don't see how this wouldn't work around the world.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for the response. So the apostrophes are redundant? Why then is there an override with both string format and culture parameters? Very unintuitive...

Comment: You _can_ have culture-dependend separators in a custom format.

Comment: @Fidor so only separators can be culture dependent, not the literals (m,d,h,etc.) themselves?

Comment: Everything is culture dependent, and even when it's not, it's because it happens to be rather than because it inherently is. You approach with apostrophes is fine, and so would be escaping them with a slash rather than apostrophes. Passing InvariantCulture is also a working option.